# java switch statement with multiple cases and case ranges

Tags: java, switch-statement

I wanted to find a way to do this in java 6, but it doesn't exist:

```
switch (c) {
  case ['a'..'z']: return "lower case" ;
```

There was a proposal to add this to the java language some time ago: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000213.html, has anything materialized in java 7?

What are other ways to rewrite this code in java 6, that would read more like a switch/case:

```
if (theEnum == MyEnum.A || theEnum == MyEnum.B){
}else if(), else if, else if...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
switch (c) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
    //...
        doSomething();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing would be:

```
if (Character.isLowerCase(c)){
    return "lowercase";
}
```

Which will also work with á ö and the sort

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if(c>='a' && c<='z')
    return "lower case";
```

Comment: in every language lowercase characters are stored in alphabet order and there are no other characters between them. It belongs to uppercase characters too.

Comment: No, it's much more complicated. That is why locale software fails on international markets. E.g. Swedish alphabet is A..Ö with Å, Ä, Ö as separate letters. German alphabet is A..Z. Ä, Ö, Ü are outside of the range but treated as the base letters. Oh, and there is the ß which does not have a capital equivalent. But the code in the question wasn't i18n safe also.

Answer (score 0):

To the first part, one options for strings

```
if(c.equals(c.toLowerCase())) return "lower case";
```

To the second part, you can use switch with enums....

```
switch(theEnum){
  case A:
  case B:
     break;
  case C:
     break;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
if (inRange(c, 'a', 'z')) {
    ...
}
```

or use a regex like normal, or a map, or...

With regards to your enum expression, it depends on what you're actually doing, but it might just be a map with implementations or values.